# DB2 query with multiple WITH AS cases not compiling

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

For some reason, I can't get this query to perform as I'm getting an error:

```
Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.
```

I'm running this in DB2 and I think this is occurring at either the very first line of the 2nd `with/as` at `) , A AS ( SELECT`

Where am I going wrong?

```
WITH
  RES (PRODUCT_ID, JOB_STATUS, JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS
(
select
    T1.NAME,
    t2.PRODUCT_id as PRODUCT_ID,
    t3.product_id,
    t3.created_at,
    t5.name as JOB_STATUS,
    t4.row_created_timestamp as JOB_STATUS_TIME ,
    t3.expiration_timestamp
from schema.PRODUCT T1
inner join schema.PRODUCT_to_product T2
on t1.PRODUCT_id = t2.PRODUCT_id
inner join schema.product t3
on t2.product_id = t3.product_id
inner join schema.product_to_job_statust t4
on t3.product_id = t4.product_id
inner join schema.job_statust t5
on t4.job_statust_id = t5.job_statust_id
where t3.job_typet_id = 2
    and t3.created_at >= '2019-09-20'
    and t5.name <> 'D'
order by t1.name,t3.product_id
)
, A AS
(
SELECT
  PRODUCT_ID, JOB_STATUS
, JOB_STATUS_TIME
, LEAD (JOB_STATUS_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT
FROM RES
)
SELECT
  PRODUCT_ID
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'O' THEN 1 END) AS CREATED
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'C' THEN 1 END) AS COMPLETED
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'X' THEN 1 END) AS CANCELLED
, SUM
  (
  CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'P' THEN
    (DAYS(JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT) - DAYS(JOB_STATUS_TIME)) * 86400
  + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(JOB_STATUS_TIME)
  END
  ) / 60 AS ACTIVE_MINUTES
FROM A
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: Remove the `order by`.  It does not belong in a CTE (or subquery).  I don't know if DB2 checks for that, but it could also be the cause of the error.

Comment: I did remove it on that principal you brought up, but it didn't fix this unfortunately

Comment: Your field list for `RES` doesn't match its `SELECT` statement and your `A` query doesn't have a field list at all...

Comment: Actually, unless running a recursive CTE, you do not need a field list.

Comment: So even by adding a field list to ```A``` or removing from ```RES``` I get the same error. This is on IBM iSeries version 7 too

Comment: You should actually be getting a more informative error on column list mismatch. See multiple scenarios with and without listed columns: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8eb711a84cc5cef6e7d218d83fc5250f). And where is the `INTO` line? Please post full error with code numbers. You might be leaving out some lines.

Comment: ```[42601][-104] [SQL0104] Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.``` is the full error code @Parfait

Comment: Try running simple final `SELECT`, then each component by itself to `SELECT * RES` and `SELECT * FROM A` to isolate the issue. To be clear you did have a syntax issue with mismatched column list that would be raised after this issue.

Comment: In the worst case scenario, start removing sections of the SQL until you identify the offendding part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always a good idea to use an SQL Editor that supports the version of Db2 that you are using.

Looking at your SQL in IBM Data Studio with the validation set to `DB2 for i 7.2`, highlights the following line in red underscores

```
, LEAD (JOB_STATUS_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT`
```

Cross referencing to the manual, I can see that `LEAD` is supported in Db2 for i 7.3 but not Db2 for i 7.2

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm

So that would be my guess at your syntax error